# Cisco SG300-28 vs Cisco/Linksys SRW2024 | Managed GB Switches

Tags: switch, gigabit-ethernet, gigabit

I'm trying to get a good managed Gigabit switch for our new 1/2 server rack, which will have about 6 servers within the next couple of months, plus firewall.

From a pricing standpoint, both of these are in the ~$500 range which is the most I can spend on the switch.

Any thoughts on these - they seem to have nearly identical features? Or am I mistaken? Is there another switch that you can recommend? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need PoE for IP phones, the SRW2024 would be best for a small environment. It comes with two shared miniGBIC ports in case you need to stack them. The web interface is better for someone that isn't strong with the Cisco CLI. [image]

Comment: Do you happen to have links to screenshots of both switches' web interfaces? I can't seem to find any!

Comment: By the way, the SRW2024 reviews on Amazon and Newegg are horrible. http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124049

Comment: I have had no switching problems with the SRW2024 but the web interface is horrible. It would lock up on us and remain unavailable until we rebooted the switch. Everything else was fine but we just couldn't administer it.

Comment: Thats interesting. Although I did notice the reviews on egghead are a few years old. For what they do and the price, I like the switches. I added a screen shot (security page) from work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used either of these switches, but we've got around a dozen of the Dell 5224 and 5324, and also a couple of 5448 48-port switches and have been very happy with them and they are definitely in your price range for the 24 port versions.